# Arraylist in koitlin from groovy

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to migrate from gradle groovy based to kotlin and want to convert the below code for ArrayList in kotlin.

```
jmUserProperties = new ArrayList();
project.properties.each{ k, v -> jmUserProperties << "${k}=" + "${v}" }
```

Any reference on how to convert above logic to kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the type of `properties`, but given your code above I think we can assume it's a `Map`. If that's the case then you can use the following code to map (i.e. transform) each key-value pair of your Map instance into a `List` of something else (in this case a list of Strings):

```
val jmUserProperties = properties.map { (key, value) -> "$key=$value" }
```

Note the resulting `List` is immutable (i.e. you can't add/remove values) and hence is not an instance of `ArrayList`. If you need a mutable list (i.e. if you want to be able to add/remove items) then you can use:

```
val jmUserProperties = properties.map { (key, value) -> "$key=$value" }.toMutableList()
```

Again, this won't necessarily return an `ArrayList` (in practice it does, but that's an implementation detail that can change at any time).

If you want to be sure to get back an `ArrayList` you can use:

```
val jmUserProperties = ArrayList(properties.map { (key, value) -> "$key=$value" })
```

Complete example:

```
// create a starting Map
val properties = mapOf(
        "key1" to "value1",
        "key2" to "value2",
        "key3" to "value3"
)

// transform the map into an ArrayList<String>
val jmUserProperties = ArrayList(properties.map { (key, value) -> "$key=$value" })

// do something with the resulting ArrayList
println(jmUserProperties)

// confirm it's an ArrayList by printing its type to stdout
println(jmUserProperties::class.java)
```

That prints:

```
[key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3]
class java.util.ArrayList
```

---

More info on what `properties.map { (key, value) -> "$key=$value" }` actually means:

- `map` is a function that can be invoked (typically) on collections and allows transforming a `Collection<A>` into a `List<B>` and takes a mapping function that transforms objects of type `A` into objects of type `B` (much like `collect` in Groovy). The syntax of the lambda should look familiar if you know Groovy.
- `(key, value)` is a [destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) and basically in this case is used to extract a key and a value from an object of type `Map.Entry` (which is what `Map`s contain in Java). More info in the documentation I linked before